# Vertex shader error C5145: must write to gl_Position using QShaderProgram

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl, shader

I am translating a Visual Studio C++ `OpenGL` project to a Qt project to implement a `UI`.

I have all the code translated and I am using Qt classes to implement `OpenGL` part.

The problem I am having now is that when I link the `shaderProgram` it throws me an error that says:

> Vertex info (0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position

I am implementing `QOpenGLFunctions_4_1_Core` and I debug the compile function to see if the code was well read and yes

All the code is read and the compile function returns a true (well compiled).

```py
GLuint shaderProgram::createShaderProgram(const char *fileName) {
    // Creamos el shader program y almacenamos su identificador
    if (handler) {
        shaderP = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
        handler = shaderP->create();
        if (!handler) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create shader program: %s.\n", fileName);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // Cargamos y compilamos cada uno de los shader objects que componen este
    // shader program
    char fileNameComplete[256];
    strcpy_s(fileNameComplete, fileName);
    strcat_s(fileNameComplete, "-vert.glsl");
    QOpenGLShader* vertex = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Vertex);
    GLuint vertexShaderObject = compileShader(fileNameComplete, QOpenGLShader::Vertex,vertex);
    if (vertexShaderObject == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    strcpy_s(fileNameComplete, fileName);
    strcat_s(fileNameComplete, "-frag.glsl");
    QOpenGLShader* fragment = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Fragment);
    GLuint fragmentShaderObject = compileShader(fileNameComplete, QOpenGLShader::Fragment, fragment);
    if (fragmentShaderObject == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    // Asociamos los shader objects compilados sin errores al shader program
    shaderP->addShader(vertex);
    shaderP->addShader(fragment);

    // Enlazamos el shader program y comprobamos si hay errores
    handler = shaderP->link(); //Here is where the error is thrown
    if(!handler)
    {
        QString error = shaderP->log();
        std::cout<< error.toStdString()<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        linked = true;
    }
    return handler;
}

bool shaderProgram::compileShader(const char *filename, QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit type,QOpenGLShader* shaderComp) {
    // Comprobamos si en la solución existe algún archivo de recursos con el
    // nombre que se pasa como argumento
    if (!fileExists(filename)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Shader source file %s not found.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
    // Si existe se lee en una cadena de caracteres que contiene el listado
    // completo del shader source
    std::ifstream shaderSourceFile;
    shaderSourceFile.open(filename);
    if (!shaderSourceFile) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open shader source file.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    std::stringstream shaderSourceStream;
    shaderSourceStream << shaderSourceFile.rdbuf();
    std::string shaderSourceString = shaderSourceStream.str();
    shaderSourceFile.close();

    // - Creamos un shader object para ese archivo que se ha leído
    QOpenGLShader shader(type);

    QString code(QString::fromStdString(shaderSourceString));

    bool result = shader.compileSourceCode(code);

    if(!result){
        const QString qs = shader.log();
        std::cout << qs.toStdString();
        this->logString = qs.toStdString();
        return false;
    }
    //si ha compilado bien, creamos el shader
    shaderComp = &shader;
    return true;
}
```

I expect the shader program link well and I would be able to draw my objects on screen.

Comment: The problem is in your GLSL shader code (and not the C++ listed above). It would be helpful to see that code (FWIW: the error is saying that your vertex shader code does not write to the gl_Position attribute, which is required as per the GLSL spec)

Comment: @robthebloke May be that there is an issue in the glsl code, but with this code no shader program will be linked successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues in your code.

First of all I recommend to us [`QOpenGLShader::compileSourceFile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglshader.html#compileSourceFile):

e.g.

```cpp
QOpenGLShader* vertex = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Vertex);
vertex->compileSourceFile( fileNameComplete );
```

---

In the function `shaderProgram::compileShader` a local variable `shader` is used:

> ```
> QOpenGLShader shader(type);
> ```

but then a pointer to this variable is assigned to the output parameter `shaderComp`.

> ```
> shaderComp = &shader;
> ```

When the function has terminated, the local object `shader` is destructed and the pointer finally goes to nowhere.

The parameter has to be an input parameter. Get rid of the local variable and use the existing object to compile the shader.
You can create a new `QOpenGLShader` object in the `shaderProgram::compileShader` and return that object by the return value:

```cpp
QOpenGLShader* shaderProgram::compileShader(
    const char *filename, 
    QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit type)
{
    // Comprobamos si en la solución existe algún archivo de recursos con el
    // nombre que se pasa como argumento
    if (!fileExists(filename)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Shader source file %s not found.\n", filename);
        return nullptr;
    }
    // Si existe se lee en una cadena de caracteres que contiene el listado
    // completo del shader source
    std::ifstream shaderSourceFile;
    shaderSourceFile.open(filename);
    if (!shaderSourceFile) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open shader source file.\n");
        return nullptr;
    }
    std::stringstream shaderSourceStream;
    shaderSourceStream << shaderSourceFile.rdbuf();
    std::string shaderSourceString = shaderSourceStream.str();
    shaderSourceFile.close();

    // - Creamos un shader object para ese archivo que se ha leído
    QString code(QString::fromStdString(shaderSourceString));

    QOpenGLShader* shader = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Vertex);
    bool result = shader->compileSourceCode(code);

    if(!result){
        const QString qs = shader->log();
        std::cout << qs.toStdString();
        this->logString = qs.toStdString();
        delete shader;
        return nullptr;
    }
    //si ha compilado bien, creamos el shader
    return shader;
}
```

Call the method like this:

```cpp
std::string vertFileName = std::string(fileName) + "-vert.glsl";
QOpenGLShader* vertex = compileShader(vertFileName.c_str(), QOpenGLShader::Vertex);
if (!vertex) {
    return 0;
}

std::string fragFileName = std::string(fileName) + "-frag.glsl";
QOpenGLShader* fragment = compileShader(fragFileName.c_str(), QOpenGLShader::Fragment);
if (!fragment) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks!