# Error compiling QOpenGLshader from source file

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, shader

I am trying to implement [a code from a paper](https://github.com/henningtjaden/RBOT). Compiling all the C++ code and everything is fine, but I encountered an error while trying to compile the shaders.

I understand QT-Desktop version append these three lines to the head of my file

```
#define lowp
#define mediump
#define highp
```

but it seems to append directly after my #version line, which causes parsing error. Any clues?

Sys Specs:

- OpenGL 4.60, Nvidia 390.87, QT 4.8.7

This is the relevant code snippet that triggers the error (while adding shader from source code)

```
if (!program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, shaderFolder + shaderName + "_vertex_shader.glsl")) {
        cout << "error adding vertex shader from source file" << endl;
        return false;
    }
```

And this is the error message.

```
***
error adding vertex shader from source file
QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): 0(36) : error C0206: invalid token "<invalid atom 50446656>" in version line

*** Problematic Vertex shader source code ***
/**
 *   #, #,         CCCCCC  VV    VV MM      MM RRRRRRR
 *  %  %(  #%%#   CC    CC VV    VV MMM    MMM RR    RR
 *  %    %## #    CC        V    V  MM M  M MM RR    RR
 *   ,%      %    CC        VV  VV  MM  MM  MM RRRRRR
 *   (%      %,   CC    CC   VVVV   MM      MM RR   RR
 *     #%    %*    CCCCCC     VV    MM      MM RR    RR
 *    .%    %/
 *       (%.      Computer Vision & Mixed Reality Group
 *                For more information see <http://cvmr.info>
 *
 * This file is part of RBOT.
 *
 *  @copyright:   RheinMain University of Applied Sciences
 *                Wiesbaden RÃ¼sselsheim
 *                Germany
 *     @author:   Henning Tjaden
 *                <henning dot tjaden at gmail dot com>
 *    @version:   1.0
 *       @date:   30.08.2018
 *
 * RBOT is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * RBOT is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with RBOT. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

#version 330#define lowp
#define mediump
#define highp
#line 37


uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
uniform mat3 uNormalMatrix;

in vec3 aPosition;
in vec3 aNormal;

out vec3 vNormal;

void main() {
    vNormal = normalize(uNormalMatrix * aNormal);

    // vertex position
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update - I have solved the problem using 2 fixes.

1. When adding the shader, I rewrote the code to essentially use the function **QOpenGLShader::CompileSourceCode** instead of **QOpenGLShaderProgram::addShaderfromSourceFile**. I used the code snippet from reference below to read the source file as a string, and then feed that string into the **CompileSourceCode** function.
2. I used

```
#version 410
```

instead of

```
#version 330
```

This was done due to the incompatibility with the layout() syntax that was used.

Reference:
[Vertex shader error C5145: must write to gl_Position using QShaderProgram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933334/vertex-shader-error-c5145-must-write-to-gl-position-using-qshaderprogram)